# как создать камеру видео наблюдения в unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет! Я создаю игру на unity 3d и мне нужно сделать камеру-видеонаблюдения.
Что бы её можно было взять и установить в какое-нибудь место.
Я хотел сделать это через RenderTexture но тогда будет ограниченное количество камер, как можно создать новую RenderTexture и сохранить её в ассетах? Или можно через другой способ?

Comment: Она не обязательно должна быть в ассетах, её можно создать кодом, сколько угодно.

Comment: А она не пропадёт если перезапустить игру?